# Why do I get different terms in same document in Lucene?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, field

I have an sentence-based index where every document stores the content and a field for every token. The content field is named `content` and stores the whole sentence as String, the token fields are named `token0`, `token1`, ... `tonken_n-1` containing each token as a String.

When I used the code sample in the Apache Migration guide to get all unique terms for each field in the example sample "This index is sentence-based.",

```
for(String field : fields) {
   Terms terms = fields.terms(field);
   TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
   BytesRef text;
   while((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
     System.out.println("field=" + field + "; text=" + text.utf8ToString());
   }
}
```

`sentence-based` is recognized as term in the field `token3`, but in the content field only `sentence` and based `based` is recognized.
It seems like `fields.terms(field)` uses a different Analyzer for each field.

I have no clue why I get different terms when applying `fields.terms("content")`.
I want to get `sentence-based` as a term out of the content field instead of `sentence` and `based`.

I hope there is an explanation for this phenomenon.

Comment: How do you split up the tokens for each token field?  And how are you indexing the content field?  `fields.terms` is no applying any analysis at all.  that would have occurred when you indexed the data.  The analysis on the content field that you've described, though sounds like typical `StandardAnalyzer` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the content field is being analyzed and the tokenN fields aren't. Analysis happens at index time, so what you need to do is revisit your indexing code and find out why content and token fields are being analyzed differently.

If you *want* the content field to be analyzed, just differently from what you have now, then okay. Do that! SimpleAnalyzer may be a good place to start.